# Ruby design question

Tags: ruby, initialization

**Overview**

I am writing a Ruby program that uses data from mysql queries to create chart URLs. A new requirement has recently surfaced where we could need to created graphs with grouped bars in the future. So instead of having one set of data, I could have any number of sets. Right now the constructor for my BarChart object only takes a single array of data, and I am looking Ruby-like ways of allowing more than one array of data.

**Current Constructor**

```
    #constructor
    #title          The title of the graph
    #data           The data that will go in the bar chart
    #labels         The labels that match the data
    #x_axis_label   The label for the x axis
    #y_axis_label   The label for the y axis
    def initialize(title, data, labels, x_axis_label, y_axis_label)
        @title, @data1, @labels, @x_axis_label, @y_axis_label = 
            title, data, labels, x_axis_label, y_axis_label

        super(@title, @@type, @@size)
        @url = to_url()
    end
```

**My attempt**

My initial thought was to use var args.

```
    #constructor
    #title          The title of the graph
    #data           The data that will go in the bar chart
    #labels         The labels that match the data
    #x_axis_label   The label for the x axis
    #y_axis_label   The label for the y axis
    def initialize(title, *data, labels, x_axis_label, y_axis_label)
        .....
    end
```

Is this a decent idea? or is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, when you have this many arguments, I would use an options hash.

```
def initialize(options = {})
  options = { default options here, if applicable }.merge(options)
  ...
end
```

So that you can construct your class like this:

```
MyClass.new(:title => "Awesome Graph", :data => [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], ...)
```

I find this approach makes your method calls much more readable, so you don't have a constructor call which has a long sequence of number and string arguments for which the meaning may be difficult to determine. This also gives you a natural way to add an arbitrary amount of optional parameters with default values.

Comment: With merge! you overwrite the parameter with your default. You can test it with:  
p ({ :a => 1}.merge!({ :a => 2 }))

Comment: Whoops. I meant to use `reverse_merge!` from ActiveSupport (it's pretty easy to bring across if you aren't using it). But I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Added ruby version dependencies

This is a decent idea but sadly it won't work in 1.8.7.

In 1.8.7. they arbitrary argument exploder (`*data`) only works at the end of the argument list. And in 1.9.2 only works if there are no optional parameters.

So something more ruby compliant like this might work,

```
def initialize(title, labels, x_axis_label, y_axis_label, *data)
    .....
end
```

However, why not simply keep data where it is and do some duck typing to see how much data is actually stored in the array. The method signature wouldn't change, but the call would slightly to,

```
Object.new(title, [data1, data2, data3], labels, ... )
```

Comment: Hmm I just read the wikipedia article on Duck Typing and im not sure if that is what I am looking for. All of the data is the same type, just instead of only having 1 data array I have 6 for example. So I was trying to use `*data` instead if having to do `data1,data2,data3,data4,data5....` Thank you for your comment, I didn't know what duck typing was :)

Comment: That's not true. There can be no *optional* parameters after the splat parameters, but mandatory ones are perfectly fine. The grammar is basically: 0 or more mandatory parameters followed by 0 or more optional parameters followed by 0 or 1 splat parameter followed again by 0 or more mandatory parameters. Arguments get bound first from the left to all the left mandatory parameters, then from the right to all the right mandatory parameters; any leftover arguments get bound left-to-right to the optional parameters and the rest get bound to the splat parameter. ...

Comment: ... If there are arguments left over, or there are unbound parameters, that is an `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Your, right! I stand corrected. Its sad this doesn't work in 1.8.7:(

Comment: @Hunter You have 6 data arrays, and 1 container array. These can be thought of as different types. I actually suspected that they would be. You could 'duck type' to test the difference between these two cases and process accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jeremy I use an option hash.

In Addition I define defaults and required keys.
Depending on my requirements I log missing/additional keys or I raise an exception. 
My Testexample code below just writes a message on stdout.

```
class X
  DEFAULTS = { 
    p1: :default1,
    p2: :default2
  }
  OBLIGATORY_PARAMETERS = [:p1]
#Parameters:
# p1
# p2
  def initialize(options = {})
    (OBLIGATORY_PARAMETERS - options.keys).each{|key|
      puts "Missing key #{key}"
    }
    (options.keys - OBLIGATORY_PARAMETERS - DEFAULTS.keys).each{|key|
      puts "Undefined key #{key}"
    }
    @options = DEFAULTS.merge(options)
  end
end

#Ok
X.new( p1: 1 )#<X:0xc8c760 @options={:p1=>1, :p2=>:default2}>
#Missing key warnings
X.new( )  ##<X:0xc8c960 @options={:p1=>:default1, :p2=>:default2}>
X.new( p2: 2 )#<X:0xc8c5c0 @options={:p1=>:default1, :p2=>2}>
#Undefined parameter -> Exception
p X.new( p3: 3 )#<X:0xc8c5c0 @options={:p1=>:default1, :p2=>2}>
```